# css3 animation-delay backward compatible alternative

Tags: css, animation

This is a straight forward question with no code (for a change) .... Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement an alternative for using animation-delay in css3... I am also looking at anything in JavaScript/Jquery that might fulfill this objective.

I basically have a background that I am using as a curtain for a loader and after about 10seconds or so It fades away leaving the main content screen.

...not that flash but don't dable much with Jquery.

```
div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use timeout to schedule it:

`ES6`

```
setTimeout( ()=> { $("#elm").hide(); }, 2e3 );
```

`ES5`

```
setTimeout( function () { $("#elm").hide(); }, 2e3 );
```

`2e3`: short for `2000`

for better performance, look at [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/)

Comment: What about this ... $(document).ready(function() {
 
 setTimeout(function(){
  $('body').addClass('loaded');
 }, 10000);
 
});

Comment: what does 2e3 mean ? and ms for the timeout do they go in the () before the = ?

Comment: @havingagoatit `2e3 === 2000`

Comment: yeah it worked but for the life of me can't find any specific conversion tables for ES5 for seconds ?? any pointers ?